# How to get historical data as a dataframe with overrides in bloomberg api using python

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to move the following Excel function to Python.

BDH("AS51 Index","BEST_EPS","2020-7-20","2021-7-20", BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE=BF,"Fill=P","Days=W","cols=2;rows=262")

There seems to be no option in blp.py to get the hisotrical data as a dataframe. Although, blp() does have an option to pass overrides but that only returns the last day price. How can i make that work to get the entire historical data as a dataframe using python?

Answer (score 1):

The `blpapi` does not natively support `pandas` DataFrames but there are various third party libraries that do. A few examples are

- [blp](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/blp)
- [pdblp](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp) (No longer recommended, better to use `blp`)
- [xbbg](https://github.com/alpha-xone/xbbg)
- [tia](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia)

Disclaimer: I am the author of the first two libraries library

Comment: Thanks Gilbert. "blp" does look like something that could be useful for me. Can you drop an example function call that could be used to retrieve historical data with overrides?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, https://matthewgilbert.github.io/blp/quickstart.html